# how to insert new some records to grid using action button in acumatica

Tags: frameworks, erp, acumatica

I have 2 tables, **Timesheet_Head** and **Timesheet_Detail**.

```
Timesheet_Head fields :
TimesheetID
Month
Year

Timesheet_Detail fields:
TimesheetID
ActivityDate
ActivityDesc
```

i want to show *some records* generated by **month** and **year** fields, from first day until last day of the month when action button clicked, for example:

```
No.   date       Description
1.    2/1/2016     
2.    2/2/2016
3.    2/3/2016
4.    2/4/2016
...   ...
29.   2/29/2016
```

does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you are trying to achieve something like that:
[expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JptHW.png)

So the action 'Generate' will look something like that:

```
public PXAction<Filter> generate;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Generate", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update, Visible = true)]
[PXButton()]
public virtual IEnumerable Generate(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    Filter filter= TranFilter.Current;
    if(filter==null || filter.Year==null)
        return adapter.Get();
    FinYear year = PXSelect<FinYear, Where<FinYear.year, Equal<Required<FinYear.year>>>>.Select(this, filter.Year);
    for (DateTime date = year.StartDate ?? DateTime.Now; date < year.EndDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
    {
        Detail row = new Detail();
        row.Date = date;
        Details.Insert(row);
    }
    return adapter.Get();
}
```

If you want to use a year actually but not a financial year I guess you should use .Net DateTime class to get first and last date of the period.